# Interpretation of quantifying information after quantum measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, information

Given initial quantum state $\rho$ of a system and $\tilde{\rho}_n$ one of the possible final states. We then define the *Groenwold information* after measurement as $$I := \langle \Delta S \rangle = S(\rho) - \sum_{n} p_n S(\tilde{\rho}_{n})$$ Where $S(\rho)$ is the entropy of density matrix $\rho$. My interpretation is that on the one hand if $I$ is large then that implies that we have more information after measurements and hence have less uncertainty. To this end, we seek to minimize $S(\tilde{\rho}_n)$ for each $n$, since by doing this we maximize $I$.

But in another sense it seems like we start with entropy (uncertainty) $S(\rho)$  and hence the smaller the term $\sum_{n} p_n S(\tilde{\rho}_{n})$ is, the less we reduce the initial uncertainty $S(\rho)$. Hence the more we can reduce the inital entropy would imply that the less uncertainty we have. But in this sense, the smaller $I$ is the more information we have, this obviously seems incorrect.

Does anyone know where my reasoning is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You used $\rho$ to denote two different objects. Then what are $p_n$ exactly? I mean, is the density matrix $\rho=\sum_n p_n |\rho_n\rangle\langle\rho_n|$?

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis No, I'm using $\rho$ to denote the initial density matrix, $\tilde{\rho}_n$ to denote a possible final density matrix with probability $p_n$  (not $\rho$) of getting the final density matrix.

Comment: oh, I see, so $p_n$ is the probability of quantum measurement of $\tilde{\rho}_n$ then.

Comment: You seem to assume $I>0$. Is that obvious?